# Javascript- form validation

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a login form validation and it's not displaying what I want. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass".value);

        //event listener
        document.getElementById("button"). onclick= function()
        {

            checkForm();

        }

        function checkForm(e)
        {
            var erroMsg = " ";

            //check email
            if(email === null)
            {
                erroMsg+= "Your email address is incorrect";
            }
            //check password
            if (pass === null)
            {
                erroMsg+= "Your password is incorrect";
            }
            //complete message
            if(erroMsg = "")
            {
                erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
            }

            alert(erroMsg);

            e.preventDefault();

        }



    </script>
```

Comment: You are not passing the event to your event handler in the registered listener function. use `onclick = function (e) { checkForm(e); };` or even better, `onclick = checkForm;`

Comment: After that change I'm still getting an alert with no message even when I click submit and leave my fields empty I get an empty alert message with no message...

Comment: @RichardJimenez I think here is a solution to  problem  given by you in below..still you faceproblem?

Answer (score 1):

**you created syntax error in 2nd line in script:**

```
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass".value);        //It should be document.getElementById("pass").value;
```

**Point 1**.You made some mistakes..some are mentioned by comment.

**Point 2**.Remember this code only deal with  the validation on empty(blank) input by user.

**Edited:**

```html
<body>
<label for="name">Email: </label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<label for="pass">Pass: </label>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
<br>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        var erroMsg = " ";
        //event listener
       document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', checkForm, false);
     
 
 function checkForm(e)
        {
    var errmsg = "";
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    //check email
    if (!email) {
     erroMsg= " Your email address is incorrect";
  }
    //check password
    if (!pass) {
      erroMsg= " Your password is incorrect";
    }
 
 if (!email && !pass) {
     erroMsg = " Your email address  and password is incorrect ";
  }
   
 
    //complete message
    if (email && pass)          //At this place you cant compare by asignment operator in ur code.
  {                     
          erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
    }

    alert(erroMsg);

    e.preventDefault();

        }
  
    



    </script></body>
</html>
```

This code considers all combination of empty input validation... Check it out!! **:)**

Comment: Thank you for that little hick up but after fixing it, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, I correct few issues in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

        //event listener
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
            checkForm();
        }

        function checkForm(e) {
            var erroMsg = "";

            //check email
            if(email === null) {
                erroMsg+= "Your email address is incorrect";
            }

            //check password
            if (pass === null) {
                erroMsg+= "Your password is incorrect";
            }
            //complete message
            if(erroMsg === "") {
                erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
            }

            alert(erroMsg);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

malformed on get value and unnecessary space on var `erroMsg`,
you also have to have the value when you click

### consider

You can just check if the variable has a **truthy** value or not. That means

```
if( value ) {
}
```

will evaluate to `true` if `value` is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

**result**

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
document.getElementById("button").onclick= checkForm;
function checkForm(e){
    var erroMsg = "";
    if(!email.value){
        erroMsg+= "Your email address is incorrect";
    }
    if (!pass.value){
        erroMsg+= "Your password is incorrect";
    }
    if(!erroMsg){
        erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
    }
    alert(erroMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', checkForm, false);

  function checkForm(e) {
    var message = "";
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    //check email
    if (!email) {
      message += "Your email address is incorrect";
    }
    //check password
    if (!pass) {
      message += "Your password is incorrect";
    }
    //complete message
    if (email && pass) {
      message = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
    }

    alert(message);

    e.preventDefault();

  }
}());
```

```html
<label for="name">Email: </label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<label for="pass">Pass: </label>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
<br>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> After that change I'm still getting an alert with no message even when I click submit and leave my fields empty I get an empty alert message with no message

That is exactly what your code is expected to do since the `erroMsg` is "(space)" and not "".

```
 ...
 //complete message
        if(erroMsg === "") {
            erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
        }

        alert(erroMsg);  // <== here
...
```

Even if your condition `erroMsg === ""` evaluates to `true` or `false`, you'll get the alert message (an empy message). And because the variable `erroMsg` is initialized with an unnecessary space, the condition may condition may never evaluate to `true`.

Try something like the following:

```
...
   checkForm(e) // <== pass on the event to the handler


...


function checkForm(e) {
        var erroMsg = ""; // <== remove the space

        //check email
        if(email === null)
        {
            erroMsg = "Your email address is incorrect";  // <== removed unnecessary + assignment.
            alert(erroMsg);
            return false;  // <== make sure the form is not submitted if not valid
        }
        //check password
        if (pass === null)
        {
            erroMsg = "Your password is incorrect";
            alert(erroMsg);
            return false; 
        }
        //complete message
        if(erroMsg = "")
        {
            erroMsg = "Form is valid!\nSubmitting...";
        }

        alert(erroMsg); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```